# How close we are to replacing guide dogs with AI?

Tags: neural-networks, applications

Were there any successful attempts to replace poor guide dogs used for blind people with AI to achieve similar rate of success? I guess dogs could be easily distracted and not reliable for every situation, and it probably takes less time to train AI, than a dog.

Comment: One key difference is that dogs need to be trained on a per-instance basis, the AI algorithm only once, then copied to all devices. Right now, though, we'd better hope the AI doesn't mistake a high-sided lorry for empty sky, like the Tesla autopilot recently did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chieko Asakawa ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chieko_Asakawa), [TED](https://www.ted.com/talks/chieko_asakawa_how_new_technology_helps_blind_people_explore_the_world?language=en), [IBM](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/view.php?person=jp-CHIE)) is a major researcher in this area, and the linked TED talk is probably a good introduction to the state of the art as of 2015. [Here's](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2899509) a link to a 2016 paper on a smartphone navigation system.

Guide animals perform manipulation tasks as well as identification tasks, and so it's not clear if those could be replaced well at all. (A smartphone that reads a label is a great help, but a dog that knows which bottle to grab and deliver to you is probably a much better help.)